# Getting null object reference error while trying to execute the Mobile automation test using Telerik Studio

Tags: java, mobile, telerik, automated-tests

For Mobile Automation - Currently I am playing with Telerik Studio

I configured all the paths and mobile devices.

I have recorded the Login scenario and when I try to execute that I am getting this error message:

```
 Step 'Tap' - FAIL
      Operation 'Tap' FAIL with: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference
```

Please let me know the solution.

Comment: Um, don't call `runOnUiThread` on a null reference? It's hard to say any more with so little information.

Comment: Error Log : 'Info: Running on device: '4f466f875b2f239f' with id: '94f50933-0d8c-4b13-a325-29e739dd09e0'
> Step 'Launch 'com.vytal.activity'' - PASS
> Step 'Tap' - FAIL
  >> Operation 'Tap' FAIL with: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference
> Step 'Tap' - SKIP
> Step 'Tap' - SKIP
> Step 'Set text' - SKIP
> Step 'Tap' - SKIP
> Step 'Tap' - SKIP
> Step 'Tap' - SKIP
> Step 'Close' - PASS
> Test Login - FAIL'

Comment: That doesn't really tell us anything about what the *code* looks like...

Comment: I am using Telerik Test Studio for Mobile Automation Testing. So only record and play scenario is there. No code at all.

Comment: So you're not actually testing your own code at all? Okay... so where does jquery-mobile come into this? Does the failure have more of a stack trace anywhere?